# retrieve usercontrol from itemscontrol item

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

i'm new to wpf and i am having a problem with items control. What i want to do is that i want to retrieve the user control that i've added in itemtemplate of items control. I tried using LoadContent() method of DataTemplate but it returns me the default template.

Here my code

```
ItemsControl parent = FindParent<ItemsControl>( this );


  //this.isEditMode = true;
  //this.editIngLayer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;


  foreach( var container in parent.Items )
  { 
    DependencyObject contentPresenter=
        parent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem( container ) as ContentPresenter;


    //Something to retrieve the usercontrol
    MyUserControl uC=contentPresenter.GetControl();
    //
  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your ItemsControl item with you then you can iterate its Visualtree to reach to your usercontrol using VisualTreeHelper

Recursive find child is explained in this post
[How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls)